# Spring, JMS and IBM MQ: right way to configure retries?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

**What are we doing?**

We are using `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` and `@JMSListener`-annotation to implement an Message-Listener for a IBM MQ queue (lets call this: `QueueA`).

When an exception is thrown within the function annotated with `@JMSListener` the current message is automatically re-queued in the connected `QueueA`. At the MQ-Server we configured a retry-count (3 retries) and after 3 un-successful retries the message is send to a backout-queue (`QueueA-BACKOUT`).

**What's our question?**

Basically we want to use the automatic mechanism provided by `@JMSListener` to re-queue a message but with a delay before doing so.

For testing purposes we use ActiveMQ. There we could easily configure an `initialRedeliveryDelay`/`redeliveryDelay` in the ConnectionFactory.

What is the equivalent way to configure something like this for IBM MQ (using the mentioned Spring Starter)?

(`INFO:` we did not implement an errorhandler for the listener yet, might this be the right place to do something like this? Or is there a simple configuration-style option to solve this?)